# How to add a dictionary to a list in robot framework

Tags: list, dictionary, robotframework

Say I have a list:

```
contacts: []
```

Now, I want to add a dictionary to this list, through a Robot Framework keyword. The `Key` of this dictionary is `email_address`, and its value is passed as an argument. This is the keyword:

```
Test keyword
[Arguments]      ${email}      #test@test.com
Append to list   ${contacts}   {"email_address":"$email"}
```

But this doesn't work. I want the final result to be like this:

```
contacts: [{"email_address":"test@test.com"}]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the dictionary first:

```
Test keyword
    [Arguments]      ${email}      #test@test.com
    &{dictionary}=    Create Dictionary    email_address=${email}
    Append to list   ${contacts}   ${dictionary}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no other way, right? I mean, I cannot do this at the same line as 'Append to list'. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
${dictionary}    Set to Dictionary    ${dictionary}    email_address=${email}
```

`Append to list` doesn't work for me too.